# Using the Node version of tsc with Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript Extension

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I've a collection of .ts files that compile without error on Windows when running tsc v1.7.5 under node.  When compiling the same files using tsc.exe v1.7.5, the compiler shows a bunch of errors in the source where there clearly are none.  I think this may be a compiler bug and I am currently working to get the minimal reproduction.

But for the meantime, I'd like to see if I can get the TypeScript 1.7.6.0 Visual Studio 2015 extension to run tsc under node instead of using the tsc.exe version.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old and it's not really answer to your question but I had the same issue with TypeScript for VS2015 recently and found a solution. I've tried installing different versions of the TypeScript plugin from offical website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 but it appears that the problem is withing the compiler, which is "bundled" with Visual Studio 2015:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe
```

Updating the extension itself is not updating the compiler which is always 1.8.34 for me. It throws "tsc.exe Exited" errors when compiling in Visual Studio
I resolved the issue by running "Repair" option on the "Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015". It just reinstalled Microsoft SDKs and problem went away. Hope it helps somebody